# Read data from database and display it in a txt file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have a table made in SQL Server 2005 which has the following columns:

```
Fname (char (50)),
MailFrom (char (50)),
MailTo (char (50)),
Subject (char (50)),
MBody (char (100)),
MailID (int)
```

After entering rows into the table, I want to extract and store them in either a text file/ document file/ window form having text fields for each column.

Any suggestions to get the best possible way to extract the data from the database and save it on a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from mytable", conn);
    DataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

    using (TextWriter writer = new TextWriter("myFile.txt"))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            StringBuilder myData = new StringBuilder();
            myData.Append(reader["Fname"].ToString();
            //etc - see how you want to format it

            writer.WriteLine(myData.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution:
If you would like to use just sql sever you will need to use bcp command.

Some facts that you need to be aware of bcp:

1. By default it connects to default sql instance, so you need to specify server if there are more than one sql server instance on the box and you are expecting to get data from other one.
2. If you are using stored procedures to retrieve data you can not use temporary tables in it, only variable tables.
3. Output will be in UTF 16, no way unfortunately to output in UTF 8.

Here you can get more information about bcp: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.90).aspx

```
    ....

    SET @SQLQuery='bcp "EXEC storedprocedure  " queryout C:\SomeFolder\'+@FileName+ ' -w -r " " -t -T -C1252 -S '+@ServerName
    PRINT @SQLQuery

    EXEC @RC = master..xp_cmdShell @SQLQuery

    ....
```

Second solution is to use SSIS package to export it to the file.

You will need to use DataFlowTask and using Database source and Flat File Destination.

Example is in here for SQL 2008 R2, but I am sure it should not much different for 2005:

http://www.kodyaz.com/ssis/export-to-text-file-using-ssis-package.aspx

Third Solutution which Haedrian suggested using programming language.

Comment: I wanted something on the beginner's foot. And honestly, I would accept it publicly, that this code was all greek to me! :P No offense, but I'm not as pro as you are! :) Cheers to your knowledge.